# How to strip out <br> tags and wrap lines with <p> and </p> tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is what the HTML code looks like.  I need to strip out the br tags and wrap the lines in paragraph tags (ie the lines with dates).  Each date should be wrapped in its own paragraph tags.

```
<html>
<head><script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


<h2>Other Events</h2>                       
<p>
<strong>Venue name</strong>
</p>
<div class="details">
<p>
Wednesday, May 11, 2011 <br>
Wednesday, June 08, 2011 <br>
Wednesday, July 13, 2011 <br>
Wednesday, August 10, 2011 <br>
Wednesday, September 14, 2011 <br>
Wednesday, October 12, 2011 <br>
Wednesday, November 09, 2011 <br>
19.00
<br>
</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I tried this block of jQuery code that I found after searching on Google, but it just doesn't work at all:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('body').html($('body').html().replace(/<br>\*/g,"</p><p>"));
});
```

I also tried this block of code, but instead of wrapping the dates in paragraph tags it put empty paragraph tags at the end of each line:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.details p br').replaceWith('<p></p>');
});
```

This is how the HTML output looked.  As you can see it hasn't wrapped the date lines with the p tags correctly:

```
<div class="details">
<p>
Wednesday, May 11, 2011 <p></p>
Wednesday, June 08, 2011 <p></p>
Wednesday, July 13, 2011 <p></p>
Wednesday, August 10, 2011 <p></p>
Wednesday, September 14, 2011 <p></p>
Wednesday, October 12, 2011 <p></p>
Wednesday, November 09, 2011 <p></p>
19.00
<p></p>
</p>
</div>
```

Does anyone know a way around this?

Comment: I would write a custom parser witch parses line-by-line and then appends valid tags wherever it's needed... :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:** By using `<p>` tags in that manner your runining it's whole *purpose* instead you should try removing the `<br>` tags and placing the text inside `<p>` elements, which will have the same effect but will be **semantically correct.**

**Edit2:** I think you wanted it in the above way, just triple read your question and I think I gotcha!

```
var $p = $('.details p');
$p.contents()
  .filter(function() { return this.nodeType == 3; }) // Select all textnodes
  .wrap('<p>') // Place them inside paragraph elements

$('br', $p).remove(); // Remove all break elements
```

**Working fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/garreh/UWDw5/1/

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly.  The reason I wanted it formatted this way is because I needed to add a jQuery toggle function to the second and subsquent date lines, so that they are hidden by default when the page loads, and then the user can click a link to reveal the other dates.  I knew that I could only attach the toggle to the paragraph elements and not to br tags.  I've got the toggle code all sorted out.  Thanks again for your help.